# Как выбрать уникальные значения из IQueryable с помощью LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, linq, entity-framework-core

Использую EF Core 3.1.13.

Есть таблица БД, в которой есть поле, которое может принимать одинаковые значения.
Необходимо вывести только уникальные значения в  IQueryable, чтобы отправить их на фронт.

Класс контекста:

```
public partial class VoterCollectorContext : DbContext
{
    public VoterCollectorContext()
    {
    }

    public VoterCollectorContext(DbContextOptions<VoterCollectorContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Как я пытаюсь это сделать:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var pollingStation = _context.PollingStation
        .Where(p => p.CityId == 1)
        .GroupBy(p => p.Name).Select(grp => grp.FirstOrDefault())
        .ToList();

    // остальной код опущен за ненадобностью
}
```

Мне выдает ошибку:

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression
> '(GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector: (p.Name),
> ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: EntityType: PollingStation
> ValueBufferExpression: (ProjectionBindingExpression:
> EmptyProjectionMember) IsNullable: False ) ) .First()' could not be
> translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
> or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
> either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or
> ToListAsync().

Как это можно сделать?

Если убрать вот эту часть:

```
.GroupBy(p => p.Name).Select(grp => grp.FirstOrDefault())
```

, то все работает норм.

Comment: `context.PollingStation.Select(x => x.Name).Distinct().ToList()`?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127038/discussion-on-question-by-vlad-i-mir------iqueryab).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если безразлично в каком порядке брать первый элемент из подгруппы, можно взять элемент с наименьшим идентификатором.

```cs
var filteredStations = _context.PollingStation
    .Where(p => p.CityId == 1);
var pollingStation = filteredStations
    .Where(p => p.Id == filteredStations.Where(x => x.Name == p.Name).Min(y => y.Id));
```

Comment: да, это помогло. Спасибо!

Comment: Как вариант, вместо `.Min(y => y.Id)` можно использовать `.First().Id`. В сгенерированном SQL вместо функции `MIN()` получится `TOP(1)`. Но это совершенно не существенно.